# DBFlow packages are missing - gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, dbflow

DBFLow packages are missing

DB Flow has 2 jars
compile "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow-core:${dbflow_version}"
compile "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow:${dbflow_version}@aar"

All the packages in dbflow-core are available but the ones in dbflow are missing while building/coding in android studio..

jar file is definitely there in the gradle cache.

Tried clearing the .gradle directory (didn't work)
Tried adding the jar file in libs folder (didn't work)

PFB the gradle file content

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

def dbflow_version = "3.0.0-beta3"

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //DBFlow
    compile "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow-core:${dbflow_version}"
    compile "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow:${dbflow_version}@aar"
    apt "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow-processor:${dbflow_version}"
    //Boiler Plate Reducers
    provided 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.6'
    apt 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.6'
    compile 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.0.4'
    apt 'org.parceler:parceler:1.0.4'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing these lines in your app's build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

You should put it before and at the same level as `dependencies`.